# Python rounding like excel round formula

Tags: python, excel-formula, rounding

I try compare multiplication of two numbers after rounding by python and excel. I use openpyxl lib.
[image]

[image] round(4190647.2349499995, 2) -> 4190647.23

But in another numbers this doesn't work!

[image]
round(3335164.9349999996, 2) -> 3335164.93

I found another "round way" in python by decimal places

```
decimal.Decimal(str(number)).quantize(decimal.Decimal(".01"), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

But it doesn't work too [image]

I add additional layer for round but doesn't work too
[image]

How I can round numbers by python like round function in excel?

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Rounding in excel and in python are different

Answer (score 0):

You can round them using the `format()` function, as follows:

```
float("{:.2f}".format(4190647.2349499995))
>>> 4190647.23
```

Comment: float("{:.2f}".format(30490740.674999997)) -> 30490740.67 but in excel -> 30490740.68

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic since Python does not work like Excel

```
d1 = 3335164.9349999996 # define a Decimal

print(round(round(d1,3),2))

>>3335164.94
```

Comment: round(round(350122.4048,3),2) -> 350122.41 but in excel -> 350122.4

Comment: then use


round(round(350122.4048,3),1)  my suggestion is not dynamic. This is a logic you can implement if you want

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with floating point rounding errors. In real maths 18.185 x 230'445.27 = 4,190,647.23495, not 4190647.2349499995, and 145.790 x 22876.5 = 3,335,164.935, not 3335164.9349999996.

You'll notice that excel has got them correctly rounded to 2dp.

Because of the quirks of binary arithmetic however these numbers are misrepresented in Python, leading to the rounding errors you're seeing.

I recommend you have a read into floats and using correctly sized floats for the arithmetic you're carrying out.

Comment: I think about it. One of my solution was convert float number from excel to string and then to decimal.
            first_number = Decimal("{:.2f}".format(ws.cell(row=row_index, column=7).value))
            second_number = Decimal("{:.2f}".format(ws.cell(row=row_index, column=8).value))
            calculated_amount = round(first_number * second_number, 2)
But result the same -> round(145.79 * 22876.5, 2) -> 3335164.93 but in excel -> 3335164.94

Comment: Right, but you're writing the numbers `4190647.2349499995` and `3335164.9349999996` into your code, not `4,190,647.23495` and `3,335,164.935`. They're different numbers - 4190647.2349499995 to 2dp and 4,190,647.23495 to 2dp both equal 4,190,647.23, whereas 3335164.9349999996 to 2dp = 3335164.93, and 3,335,164.935 to 2dp = 3,335,164.94.

Comment: round(decimal.Decimal("20.50") * decimal.Decimal("973.21"), 2) -> Decimal('19950.80') but in excel 19950.81

Comment: Is there a reason you're so keen to use the `Decimal()` function? If you use `format(float(20.50 * 973.21), '.2f')`, you'll get `'19950.81'` which is correct

Comment: or that, it's also correct!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, how i may do it into python code? If I use -> first_number = ws.cell(row=row_index, column=7).value second_number = ws.cell(row=row_index, column=8).value calculated_amount = round(first_number * second_number, 2)
Then -> 145.79 * 22876.5 = 3335164.9349999996 after python round -> 3335164.93 but in excel -> 3335164.94

Comment: If i use first_number = Decimal(ws.cell(row=row_index, column=7).value) second_number = Decimal(ws.cell(row=row_index, column=8).value) calculated_amount = round(first_number * second_number, 2) Then -> 145.789999999999992041921359486877918243408203125 * 22876.5 = 3335164.9349999996. In python round -> 3335164.93 and in excel ->3335164.94

Comment: If I use first_number = Decimal("{:.3f}".format(ws.cell(row=row_index, column=7).value))
second_number = Decimal("{:.2f}".format(ws.cell(row=row_index, column=8).value)) calculated_amount = round(first_number * second_number, 2) Then -> 20.500 * 973.21 = 19950.805. In python round -> 19950.80 in excel -> 19950.81

Comment: Can you help me? What I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens if you do: `first_number = Decimal(ws.cell(row=row_index, column=7).value)` `second_number = Decimal(ws.cell(row=row_index, column=8).value)` `calculated_amount = first_number * second_number` `rounded = format(calculated_amount, '.2f')`?

Comment: If I use -> first_number = Decimal(ws.cell(row=row_index, column=7).value) second_number = Decimal(ws.cell(row=row_index, column=8).value) calculated_amount = first_number * second_number rounded = format(calculated_amount, '.2f') Then -> 145.789999999999992041921359486877918243408203125 * 22876.5 = 3335164.9349999996 In python -> 3335164.93 In excel ->3335164.94

Answer (score 0):

Python delegates floating point arithmetics to your hardware: from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

*Almost all machines today (November 2000) use IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic, and almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision”. 754 doubles contain 53 bits of precision, so on input the computer strives to convert (the value) to the closest fraction it can of the form J/2**N where J is an integer containing exactly 53 bits".*

Excel probably uses some tricks under the hood to correct (most of) the inherent inexactness of floating point. So the short answer is: you can't have Python working exactly as Excel in all cases, unless you know Excel internals.

That said, in the document I linked you will find some detailed explanations, and also some ways to circumvent the issue. Then, there is one common trick you may want to try, *if you know the max number of decimal digits your values will have*: assume that number is `d`; then you can multiply your values by `10**d` and cast them to integers, multiply them, and then round to the required number of decimals the quotient of the product divided by `10**(d*2)`. Step by step:

```
d=3
a=int(145.79*10**d)          ## 145,790
b=int(22876.5*10**d)         ## 22,876,500
round(a*b/10**(d*2),2)
3335164.94
```

or, as a one-liner

```
round(int(145.79*10**d)*int(22876.5*10**d)/10**(d*2),2)
3335164.94
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, trick doesn't work in this situation: d = 3 round(int(24961.7*10**d)*int(1296.45*10**d)/10**(d*2),2) In python -> 32361595.96, In excel -> 32361595.97

Comment: This is another issue - Python rounds 0.5 to the nearest even number, so .965 -> .96, while .975 -> .98

Answer (score 0):

In excel, the round() function uses a banker's rounding logic when the rounding digit being considered is 5. If digit is 0-4, round-down, if it is 6-9, then round-up. If it is 5, consider its preceding digit: if it is even (0,2,4,6,8) then round down, if it is odd (1,3,5,7,9) then round-up.

Below is a function to perform Excel style rounding. It works well for 6 decimal places. You may edit the values to increase the precision.

```
import pandas as pd
import maths

def excel_round(x, d):
    ''' Function for MS Excel like rounding-off of decimal numbers
        x (float) = value, d (int) = number of decimal places 
    '''
    # Example:
    # round(0.105, 2) = 0.10 ;  round(0.115, 2) = 0.12
    # excel_round(0.105, 2) = 0.11 ;  excel_round(0.115, 2) = 0.12 

    if pd.isnull(x):
        return x
    
    val = int(x * math.pow(10,d)) / math.pow(10,d)
    rem = (x - val) * math.pow(10,d+1) + 0.0000001
    dig = int(rem)

    num = val
    if dig >= 5.00000:
        num = val + float(1/(10 ** d))
    
    return (num)
```